# NSEnumerator memory leak

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks

This leaks like mad, due to the way I use enumerators.  Why?  It leaks even more severely if I don't release the enumerator - I understand that much.. but I don't understand why this still leaks.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   // insert code here...
   NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

   // Create an array and fill it with important data!  I'll need to enumerate this.
   NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:300];

   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 200; i++)
     [myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];

   while(1)
   {
      NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myArray objectEnumerator];
      // Imagine some interesting code here
      [enumerator release];
   }

   // More code that uses the array..

   [pool drain];
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't leak, per se — and you shouldn't release the enumerator.

A memory leak is when memory is left allocated but can no longer be released (typically because you no longer have a pointer to it). In this case, the enumerator will be released when the autorelease pool drains, but you're preventing the program from reaching that line with your loop. That's why the enumerators pile up. If you change the loop to:

```
while(1)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *innerPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myArray objectEnumerator];
    [innerPool drain];
}
```

you'll find that your memory consumption remains constant, because the enumerator will be properly released at the end of each iteration.

Comment: +1: I was in the middle of writing this same explanation; you beat me to it.

Comment: So to clarify - there's autorelease'd stuff being done inside foundation, and I basically have to drain a pool to acknowledge that I'm done with my current processing and it's time to move on?

Comment: No, what you're describing is cooperative multitasking - things haven't worked that way since Windows 3 & MacOS "classic." Draining the pool releases the memory used by the objects inside it, that's all; it has nothing to do with being "done with my current processing," it's just memory allocation.

Comment: @Nektarios: It's not really anything to do with the "current processing." This technique just makes autoreleased objects get *actually* released sooner. Each thread effectively has a stack of autorelease pools. When you create a pool, it's put on top. When an object is autoreleased, it goes into its thread's top pool. When an autorelease pool is drained, it releases all the objects that have been put in it and pops itself from the stack of pools. The pool we're creating here is created at the beginning and destroyed at the end of each loop iteration, so objects don't get a chance to pile up.

Answer (score 0):

It leaks because your outermost autorelease pool only gets to do its thing once. Any autoreleased objects created within the while(1) loop will just sit around consuming memory until your program flow gets to the [pool drain] at the end.

To avoid this, create additional nested autorelease pools inside your loop, like this:

```
while(1) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *innerPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // .. Do a bunch of stuff that creates autoreleased objects
    [innerPool drain];
}
```

This approach is similar to how AppKit works, creating and draining a new autorelease pool for each iteration through its event loop.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here. I think this answer is better than mine as far as concision goes (and it goes very far in my book).

Comment: I suspect it's just a case of childish people with voting privileges. Whoever it was apparently followed my profile to vote down another answer I posted way back in '08. Some people just have nothing better to do than pee in the pool. Their vote says more about their own character than it does about my answers, so I don't lose any sleep over it.