# Having trouble with this alloc/releasing issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I've tried numerous different attempts at it but always ends in leaks or errors. So here is my code, with the allocating and releasing bits taken out. I'd like to know how people suggest i should go about doing this?

.h

```
#import "MatchingColors.h"

@interface MagicSchemeView : UIViewController {

    NSMutableArray *colors;

}
```

.m

```
colors = [MatchingColors monochromaticWithH:h S:s B:b WithComplementary:NO];
```

Then in MatchingColors.m:

```
+(NSMutableArray *)monochromaticWithH:(float)h S:(float)s B:(float)b WithComplementary:(BOOL)complementary {

    return result;

}
```

Like i say, my attempts at allocating and releasing here seem to be going wrong. Ideas?

Comment: He's creating a new array.  MagicSchemeView and MatchingColors are two different classes.

Comment: Ah - I see what he's doing now.

Comment: I don't know how you're seeing leaks or what your experience level is, but the actual problem could be because you aren't using autorelease pools properly.  If so, you'll end up with leaks but your main code is actually correct.  See this post about me making that nasty mistake: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383463/nsenumerator-memory-leak

Answer (score 2):

This should work

A place for the [colors release]; would be after you're done with it.  Which would be as soon as you know you don't need it, or would be done on dealloc.  Make sure dealloc is a last resort to put this release.

```
.m:

colors = [[MatchingColors monochromaticWithH:h S:s B:b WithComplementary:NO] retain];


+(NSMutableArray *)monochromaticWithH:(float)h S:(float)s B:(float)b WithComplementary:(BOOL)complementary 
{      
    NSMutableArray *result = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    // Create the result here

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should really have a `retain` for the assignment to `colors` and an `autorelease` for the object returned from the class method. It works as it stands, but breaks the Cocoa convention of returning autoreleased objects from all methods apart from those that have the words `alloc`, `copy`, or `new`

Comment: You're completely right, and I've adjusted my answer because it more closely matches what the OP probably wants.  Thank you Abizern